# Generator model TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use this code to make the generator function , it's working with shape =(256,256,3)
But I'm trying to use it with shape=(112,112,3) but it's getting this error

Error:

```
A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. 
Received: input_shape=[(None, 2, 2, 512), (None, 1, 1, 512)]
```

Here is the code

```
def Generator():
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[112, 112, 3])

  down_stack = [
    downsample(64, 4, apply_batchnorm=False),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 64)
    downsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 128)
    downsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 256)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 1, 1, 512)
  ]

  up_stack = [
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 1024)
    upsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 512)
    upsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 256)
    upsample(64, 4),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 128)
  ]

  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(OUTPUT_CHANNELS, 4,
                                         strides=2,
                                         padding='same',
                                         kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                         activation='tanh')  # (batch_size, 256, 256, 3)

  x = inputs

  # Downsampling through the model
  skips = []
  for down in down_stack:
    x = down(x)
    skips.append(x)

  skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

  # Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
  for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
    x = up(x)
    print(x.shape,skip.shape)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, skip])

  x = last(x)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you downsample by 2 and upsample by 2 each time. It means the input **must be divisible by 2**, that's why 256 input shape works.

In your case

112 / 2 = 56

56 / 2 = 28

28 / 2 = 14

14 / 2 = 7 # no longer divisible by 2

downsampling 7 by 2 will give you shape of 3. And when you will upsample 3 by 2 it will give you 6 and you will not be able to concatenate layer with shape 6 and 7.

I suggest 2 options:

1. use 128 instead of 112 if its possible in your application
   and remove one pair of downsampling, upsampling.

```
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[128, 128, 3])

  down_stack = [
    downsample(64, 4, apply_batchnorm=False),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 64)
    downsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 128)
    downsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 256)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 512)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 512)
#    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 1, 1, 512)
  ]

  up_stack = [
#    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 1024)
    upsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 1024)
    upsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 512)
    upsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 256)
    upsample(64, 4),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 128)
  ]
```

2. Use 112, but stop downsampling before the input is no longer divisible by 2

```
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[112, 112, 3])

  down_stack = [
    downsample(64, 4, apply_batchnorm=False),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 64)
    downsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 128)
    downsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 256)
    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 512)
#    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 512)
#    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 512)
#    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 512)
#    downsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 1, 1, 512)
  ]

  up_stack = [
#    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 2, 2, 1024)
#    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 4, 4, 1024)
#    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # (batch_size, 8, 8, 1024)
#    upsample(512, 4),  # (batch_size, 16, 16, 1024)
    upsample(256, 4),  # (batch_size, 32, 32, 512)
    upsample(128, 4),  # (batch_size, 64, 64, 256)
    upsample(64, 4),  # (batch_size, 128, 128, 128)
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you , your answer is really helpful @nick